# Compare two components by NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I want to query an `NSDictionary` of contacts using `NSPredicate`. I am able to search the contacts using the "firstName" and "lastName" separately, but I also need to search the contacts whose complete name is entered.

For example: If I want to search a contact with name "John Doe", and I search by entering search key "John" or "Doe", I am able to get the name, but I also want it to be searchable when I enter search key "John Doe". Currently I am using :

```
NSPredicate *p1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastNames BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText];
NSArray *p1FilteredArray = [allContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p1];
NSPredicate *p2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstNames BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText];
NSArray *p2FilteredArray = [allContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p2];
searchedArray = [[p1FilteredArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:p2FilteredArray] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: if you are not using _CoreData_, the block-based predication would be more convenient for you.

Comment: @holex There are times that I'd fall back to the flexibility of the block-based implementation, but I'm not sure as I'd describe it as more convenient.

Comment: @Rob I would like to know why block-based implementation is not a convenient solution. I am able to use holex's solution as I need, but would like to know the pros and cons of it.

Comment: That's not what I said. Neither is especially "more convenient" than the other. If you were to push me on the point, I think [`predicateWithFormat`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25688060/1271826), is a tad more intuitive and easier to read than the block-based implementation, but to each his own. Use whichever you'd like, as both will do the job fine. My point was simply that I disagree that the block-based rendition is any more convenient, much less that this has anything to do with whether you're using with _CoreData_ or not.

Comment: Re pros and cons, I think `predicateWithFormat` is wonderful, as the format string can generally express the intent more concisely and elegantly than I can achieve in code (the two answers below are a wonderful illustration of this, IMHO). The block-based rendition, though, is invaluable, when doing something especially complicated, which cannot be effectively expressed in the format string. I also suspect that the block-based rendition is a tad more efficient, but I've never benchmarked it, so I can't say.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the detailed explanation, and I do consider readability an important aspect. But this time I think I'd go with holex's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like e.g. this:

```
NSArray *_allContacts = // ...;
NSString *_searchText = // ...;
NSArray *_result = [_allContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary * evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return ([[[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"lastNames"] lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[_searchText lowercaseString]] || [[[evaluatedObject valueForKey:@"firstNames"] lowercaseString] hasPrefix:[_searchText lowercaseString]]);
}]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use single predicate with `or` operator:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstNames beginswith[cd] %@ or lastNames beginswith[cd] %@", searchTerm, searchTerm];

NSArray *results = [allContacts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```